# Какого рода слово "кофе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Понятно, что "кофе" — слово мужского рода (что бы там ни напридумывали новые реформы). Но как быть с сортами кофе? Например, как сказать: "Мне один латте" или "мне одно латте"? Или "мне один эспрессо" или "мне одно эспрессо"?

Comment: Это всё-таки не сорта кофе, а разные напитки. Сорта это арабика, робуста и т.п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала. Словари потихоньку сдаются и признают частичную нормативность среднего рода для слова кофе. На уровне разговорной допустимости.
В отношении  самого вопроса: общих рекомендаций тут нет. В данном случае, думаю, следует руководствоваться родом т.н. родового слова кофе (простите за невольный каламбур, не могу по-другому сказать), т.е. нормативно - мужским.